# Calculating closest distances in meters/kilometers given lat/long coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2, distance

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

I have a shape file containing points worldwide with lat and long, and another world map polygon file whose Geographic Coordinate System is GCS_WGS_1984 and Datum is D_WGS_1984.  I want to use Generate Near Table (Analysis) tool to search for polygons within 100 miles within each point and displaying distance in meters, kilometer, or miles.

I have looked for a solution for a while, one suggested me projecting my points using 'WGS_1984_EASE_Grid_Global'.

Any comments?

Comment: Can you edit your Question to include what happened when you tried using the suggested coordinate system, please?

Comment: Since the points are worldwide, no single projection will provide reasonably accurate solutions. One line of attack is to perform the calculation point by point, changing the projection to be suitable in the vicinity of each point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I learned a lesson.  Just curious how inaccurate it would be if radius of each point I mostly care about is 100 miles or 25 miles?  If it is within 10%, it is accepted to me for the current use.